# ArrayList from txt file trouble

Tags: java, arraylist

4 Classes:

1. `Party` - index, a name, a location, and list of a number of creatures (accessed by links to instances of the Creature class).
2. `Creature` - index, a type, a name, party by index, empathy value, fear value, list of treasures, list of artifacts
3. `Treasure` - index, type, creature by index, weight, value
4. `Artifact` - index, type, creature by index, other fields

Use the ArrayList class to hold instances of the classes above.

test data (looks something like):

```
p : 10003 : Conglomeration

c : 20001 : Woman   : Lucy   :10001 : 17 : 22 : 20

t : 30004 : Silver : 20005 : 120 : 1000

a : 40001 : Wand : 20007 : ElderWand
```

This is what I've written so far:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SorcerersCave {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<Party> partyList = new ArrayList<Party>();
        ArrayList<Creature> creatureList = new ArrayList<Creature>();
        ArrayList<Treasure> treasureList = new ArrayList<Treasure>();
        ArrayList<Artifact> artifactList = new ArrayList<Artifact>();


            // open and read file:
            try {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(chooser.getSelectedFile())
                        .useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*");

                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

                    String line = scanner.nextLine();

                    int index;
                    String type;
                    String name;

                    char identifier = line.charAt(0);

                    if (identifier == 'p') {
                        index = scanner.nextInt();
                        name = scanner.next();
                        partyList.add(new Party(partyInfo(index, name)));

                    } else if (identifier == 'c') {
                        index = scanner.nextInt();
                        type = scanner.next();
                        name = scanner.next();
                        int partyC = scanner.nextInt();
                        int empathyC = scanner.nextInt();
                        double carryingCapacityC = scanner.nextDouble();
                        creatureList.add(new Creature(creatureInfo(index, type,
                                name, partyC, empathyC, carryingCapacityC)));

                    } else if (identifier == 't') {
                        index = scanner.nextInt();
                        type = scanner.next();
                        int creatureT = scanner.nextInt();
                        double weightT = scanner.nextDouble();
                        int valueT = scanner.nextInt();
                        treasureList.add(new Treasure(treasureInfo(index, type,
                                creatureT, weightT, valueT)));

                    } else if (identifier == 'a') {
                        index = scanner.nextInt();
                        type = scanner.next();
                        int creatureA = scanner.nextInt();
                        artifactList.add(new Artifact(artifactInfo(index, type,
                                creatureA)));

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("This is not a valid line of input");
                    }
                    System.out.println("Identifier: " + identifier);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("party: " + partyList.toString());
        }
    }

    private class Creature {

    public Creature (int index, String type, String name,
            int partyC, int empathyC, double carryingCapacityC) {
        return;
    }
}
    private class Party {

        public Party(int index, String name) {
            return;
        }
    }

    private class Artifact {

        public Artifact(int index, String type, int creatureA) {
            return;
        }
}
        private class Treasure {
            public Treasure(int index, String type, int creatureT,
                    double weightT, int valueT) {
                return ;
            }

}
```

I know I already have issues because when I try to print the contents of the partyList array. It's empty. I just can't seem to figure out why.

Errors present:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at SorcerersCave.main(SorcerersCave.java:43)
```

Idea**  Is it possible for me to have the if-else loop and 'look to' corresponding class to see what to scan (instead of doing it all in the loop)? For example: if the first letter is a 'p' go to the party class to see what to do with the line.

Comment: Please remove all the GUI stuff and post only the code related to parsing your input.

Comment: And the steps you've used so far to diagnose the problem?

Comment: I'd also recommend that you put your static data in an XML file because its starting to get kinda lengthy and detailed.

Comment: I removed a bunch... better? (sorry about that)

Comment: What I am curious it is why you are performing role of Human Debugers, the question is changed each time someone catch some issue. I know that we should help each other out. But from my point of view, the OP do not have any clue how to dell with basic problems. He only copy paste some skeletal implementation and now you all help him to resolved it. I might be concerned as a pain in the ***. But this is against the SO policy i think. If am wrong please correct me.

Comment: I only edited my question because new questions arose as everyone assisted me (i.e. when I removed code as suggested, the errors were seen). I was not aware that this was against any policy, if so I do apologize. My original question remains the same though. Which is why the arrayList appears to be empty- I now see that this has something to do with the format of my input data, and am working on the issue.

Comment: Check the edit in my answer. I believe it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you scan through all the input in these lines:

```
           while (scanner.hasNext())
                    System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
```

Also your classes seem unusual. Why use `static Object`?
Just build conventional classes for each of the types, for example:

```
private class Creature{
   // data fields

   public Creature(int index, String type, String name, int partyC, int empathyC, double carryingCapacityC){
      // set data field values
   }

   // accessors, mutators etc.
}
```

**Something like this:** http://goo.gl/hM2Fo

Comment: Actually... this might be it. Let me try changing that!

Comment: Okay! now I'm coming up with some errors (i'll post them in my question)

Comment: `System.out.println` is your friend. Use it to see stages in your code. For example, print the value of `String line = scanner.nextLine();` just to see if the code reaches it.

Comment: Well it wont print anything because I think it's stuck on the 'InputMismatchException'... which means that I told it to look for something it can't find right? (i.e. look for an int but the next thing wasn't an int?)

Comment: Your new error suggests that you're trying to scan a double, but the next token is not a double.

Comment: Yeah that's right. But the exception is triggered at line 43, way after you're actually reading the line.

Comment: Here were your problems: 1) You have to create a new scanner to scan the line of text. Once you've scanned `nextLine()` the scanner moves on to the next line of the file. 2) You have to call `lineScan.next()` in order to scan past the identifier char. 3) I'm not sure if your delimiter pattern was correct - use the use I suggested and make sure your input data is formatted correctly. 4) You should practice debugging. And read about Scanners and Classes and things - study the API. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i haven't worked much with lineScan but that does make sense. I'll take a look at this and modify my final code when everything is complete. I think the delimiter should work as long as the .txt file is in the correct format- which shouldn't be a problem since I pretty much have free reign w/ that.

Answer (score 1):

My advise on this, you should try to use the Debug mode.

PS. main problem is that you try to create an object from nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not reading it wrong all of your objects return null. You are then trying to append a null reference onto the arrayList and it is ignoring it. Try actually making objects and see the results.

from the Collections javadoc on add()

```
Collections that support this operation may place limitations on what elements may be 
added to this collection. In particular, some collections will refuse to add null
elements, and others will impose restrictions on the type of elements that may be added.
Collection classes should clearly specify in their documentation any restrictions on what  
elements may be added.
```